# If you're a .NET developer, does getting the Microsoft Certified Master SQL Server 2008 cert make sense?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I've been working at a job for the past year as a .NET developer/DBA.  The job is my first DBA job.  Traditionally, I'm a .NET developer and have about 5 years experience in it.

Does it make sense for me to continue my certs to get the MCM (assuming I'm eligible)?  I'm thinking it doesn't because I've been working with SQL Server for 5 years but only as a DBA for a year.

Would it help a developer to have that?  Or is it useful only in switching?  I became interested in SQL Server because I felt that during the recession, people were looking more and more for developers who could add value across the stack.  Now, I'm not so sure...

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'd say, it's always worth getting a certification if your company is going to pay for it. ;)

If you're paying for it yourself, I'd only do it if I was pretty sure I was going to get a good return on my investment. Remember, as soon as the next version comes out, your certification is worthless.

Comment: This, basically.  If your company will pay for it, there's no harm.  If you have to pay for it yourself, only if it's worth getting in your area.

Answer (score 1):

> *Does getting the Microsoft Certified Master SQL Server 2008 cert make sense?*

**No**.

Based on the cost for the [MCM program](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/certification/master.aspx), I'd say "if you have to ask, then the answer is no". I would do the MCITP for DB Admin and DB Developer, but unless the company was willing to pay the $18,500 for the MCM (this does not include hotel accomodations in Redmond, nor plane trips there), I sure would not bother with the master cert.

Comment: It isn't $18,500 anymore.  They have made it available at a distance for $2,500.